# Block arrangement algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

Need some help with the following algorithm:

I need an algorithm to arrange M blocks on a grid such that they remain connected (share edge or corner). The arrangements should be unique such that by rotating or mirroring, one cannot get same arrangement.

For example, for M=3, arrangements are:

```
o  o  o
-----
o
o  o
------
o
  o  o
------
o
  o
    o
------
o   o
  o
------
```

I need to write a program in C that can:

```
   - the number of such arrangements
   - print the arrangements as above
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a basic tree search algorithm. Just think how to represent the solution space as a tree...

Comment: An even simpler but more expensive (in CPU time) approach would be to generate every possible permutation (9 spots, 3 blocks, would be 9C3 = 84 combinations), and then run a test function on each result to determine if it's valid.

Comment: Is this for Tic-Tac-Toe ?

Comment: Im thinking about doing it using vector addition. Every block can be a unit vector in 8 possible directions.  For uniqueness of the vector, length of its resultant could be used. Any ideas?